# SELECT records from exact day to exact day

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I need to SELECT all records from exact day to exact day. For example from 2013-03-05 0:00 to 2013-03-20 0:00 in TIMESTAMP type

Comment: oh wow, so much own research effort, have a look into: `... BETWEEN DATE() AND DATE...` and maybe `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`

Comment: and the question is?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this you can use `between` function also

```
select * from table where date_column between '2013-01-10 00:00:00'  and '2013-06-12 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date1 => '2013-03-05 0:00' AND date2 <= '2013-03-20 0:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you want to break it (e.g. if you want to go from 2013-03-05 00:00:00 to 2013-03-19 23:59:59) you should be able to just use >= / < on your date fields:

```
SELECT *
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE date_field >= '2013-03-05' 
   AND date_field < '2013-03-20'
```

Comment: (If you want to include 2013-03-20 00:00:00 then use "<=" in the second clause)